# caterpillar identification and eradication

Tags: insects

Can you help me identify this type of caterpillar and what is the solution to eradicate them? i keep removing them from the tree but after a few days I find them again...

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you remove them?

Comment: Just picked them with a tissue and threw them to the bin. But I suspect there are some eggs somewhere.
I started to use some fertiliser (horse stool) recently, could they come from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general approach to pest removal is to spray them with soap water. Just mix a bit of soap with some water, and spray the entire plant (leaves and all). The soap is harmless enough to the plant, and annoying enough to most critters to persuade them to leave.

This approach is useful in cases of some level of infestation (since you suspect eggs). I would suggest try this first, although it may not solve your problem entirely (or at all).